# Draw a rectangle around bars and categories in (R, ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a box/rectangle around a single level of a category and include the axis category text and the bar itself:

[image]

As you can see in the photo, the rectangle extends beyond the grid and into the plot area to encompass the axis text. I'm hoping for something customizable so I can draw rounded corners or not, change the color, and specify where it goes.

Here's some generic code I used to produce a plot:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl)))+
  geom_bar(stat="count", width=0.7, fill="steelblue")+
  theme_minimal()
```

Hopefully, this isn't answered somewhere already!

Answer (score 2):

1. For rectangle use `annotate` with `"rect"`
2. to go over the x axis you can set the x axis to blank
3. then add new quasi axis with `geom_text` setting y to 0 or -1. play around to fit:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl)))+
    geom_bar(stat="count", width=0.7, fill="steelblue")+
    theme_minimal() 
    

p + annotate("rect", xmin = 0.5, xmax = 1.5, ymin = -1, ymax = 12,
             alpha = 0, color= "green") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            axis.line.x = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
    geom_text(aes(y = -0.5, x = factor(cyl), 
                  label = cyl)) +
    labs(title="Rectangle over x axis!",
          x ="cyl", y = "count")
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can use `coord_cartesian(ylim = ..., clip = "off")` and increase the lower margin with `theme(plot.margin = `

Comment: I just took out the grid lines (which was how I had it anyway) and it worked. This is a great workaround and worked with my actual dataset.

Comment: I wanted to use this in a function and have `ymin(), ymax(), xmin(), xmax()` to take a value specified in a column. For example: `ymin = max(count)` if `count` was a column in the df. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `ggforce` package is great for. Here with a semi-programmatic approach to define x/y coordinates of your shape. If you intend to mark specific areas / data points, you might also want to look into `ggforce::geom_mark_rect`

I have also un-factorised the x.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

cyl <- 4
n_cyl4 <- table(mtcars$cyl)[1]
df_rect <- data.frame(x = c(cyl - .5, rep(cyl + .5, 2), cyl - .5), y = c(rep(-2, 2), rep(n_cyl4 + .5, 2)))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl)) +
  geom_shape(data = df_rect, aes(x, y), fill = NA, color = "black", radius = .01) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count", width = 0.7, fill = "steelblue") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(4, 8, 2)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, NA), clip = "off") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This one doesn't include the x-axis text in the box. Can you do that with `ggforce()` ?

Comment: Of course. This requires a bit more fiddling with the x/y coordinates though. See update